# Нужна помощь с one to many. Django

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте, в `models.py` у меня:

```
class user(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_id

class messages(models.Model):
    mes = models.ForeignKey(user)
```

Но не могу никак разобраться, как добавлять к одному `user` много `mes`. Можете объяснить или дать пинок в нужном направлении?

Comment: `message1 = messages(mes=ваш_user); message2 = messages(mes=ваш_user)` и так далее, что непонятно?

Comment: И я бы назвал это поле не `mes`, а, например, `author`. А так, Ваш код - то что Вам и нужно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поправил немного ваш код, и добавил комментариев что к чему.

```
class User(models.Model):
    # поле id создасться автомататически, поэтому самим создавать его не надо
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return "пользователь: " + self.name

class Message(models.Model):
    # это поле необходимо для связи с таблицей пользователя
    user = models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    # текст сообщения пользователя.
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

user1 = User.objects.create(name="Андрей")  # создали пользователя
m1 = Message.objects.create(user=user1, text="текст сообщения")  # создали пару сообщений
m2 = Message.objects.create(user=user1, text="ещё текст сообщения")

# таким способом можно находить все сообщения данного пользователя
messages = Message.objects.filter(user=user1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для админки

```
from .models import *
class messagesAdminInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = messages
    extra = 2 # Количество полей
class userAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = [field.name for field in user._meta.fields]
    inline = [messageAdminInline]
    class Meta():
        model = user
admin.site.register(user, userAdmin)
```